# Python syntax in django tutorial

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was reading the tutorial [here] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/)

And could not understand this python syntax:

```
>>> q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

This works on Python 2.7 for me. Never seen this before.

Here is the Question class:

```
class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: Object creation? Named parameters?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Not quite, see my edit above.

Comment: this is what is called a ORM, this is an object that replaced an sql statement

Comment: @Abdelouahab Any more details on how the constructor is actually working ?

Comment: Question inherits models.Model. Model has a kwarg constructor.

Comment: you already inherited from `models.Model` which already has a constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax in python called `named arguments`.

**For example**

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, *l, **d):
        print d


>>>Myclass(arg1="val1", arg2="val2")
{'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2'}
```

By this way Django models.Model take `*args` and `**kargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Django `models.Model` take `*args` and `**kargs`, and use `setattr` to initialize object values.